# How to print system logs on web page with Ajax/java script

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, ubuntu, logging

I installed a software In my Ubuntu system  . It will write and update logs on `/var/log/my_software/logs.txt`  . My aim is to print this logs on a web page . I am using Apache web server .

I am printing the logs with  `tailf /var/log/my_software/logs.txt` command . Now i want to show this logs inside a `DIV in HTML file` . Also i want to update this logs every time when my software update it's logs .

Which method should i choose for implementing this concept  ? I am not using PHP in my web server . `I am comfortable with Ajax or Jquery` .

Any suggestions or useful links , code stubs ?

Answer (score 0):

First check file has been updated or not using 
[Execute JavaScript if HTML file has been updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006136/execute-javascript-if-html-file-has-been-updated)

Then if file has been modified you can update your html with this
[jQuery: load txt file and insert into div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470567/jquery-load-txt-file-and-insert-into-div)